# Javascript not being triggered by a partial view button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a modal, with the contents kept in a partial view, that appears when you click the button on the main view that contains a table of entries.

When I try to create a new entry for my table using the modal box 'Create' button, the button doesn't trigger the javascript function? My Javascript is in the main view (I've also tried adding it to the partial view) and appears to just get completely ignored when I press the button.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <button id="btnCreateNew" type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary Creationbtn" style="background-color:darkorange; border-color:orangered;">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I've tried a fair few solutions to get it to work, but it still doesn't get triggered, I've tried adding the `onclick` property to the button too, but that also doesn't work. When I change the button to submit type, it just triggers my JsonResult function in my controller instead.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.Creationbtn', function () {
        debugger;
        var PostURL = '@Url.Action("CreateNew")';
        var pidEntered = $('#ddlWithWhom').val();
        pidEntered = parseInt(pidEntered);
        var notesEntered = $('#NoteEditor').val();
        var eidEntered = $('#ddlWhatHappen').val();
        var dateEntered = $('#DateEditor').val();
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: PostURL,
            data: { pid = pidEntered, notes = notesEntered, eid = eidEntered, date = dateEntered },
            success: function (response) {
                window.location = "Index.html";

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Fail")
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the javascript that triggers the modal too if it's necessary

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $(".anchorNew").click(function () {
            var PostBackURL = '/PersonEvents/CreateNew';
            debugger;
            var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
            var myModal = document.getElementById("showModal");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: PostBackURL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#showModal').modal(options);
                    myModal.style.display = "block";

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                }
            });
        });
        //$("#closebtn").on('click',function(){
        //    $('#myModal').modal('hide');

        $("#closbtn").click(function () {
            $('#showModal').modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm fairly new to Javascript so forgive me if I've missed something obvious or if more of my code is needed. Thanks for any help!

Edit: thanks to @Swati, the javascript now triggers, though now the data in the ajax request seems to get lost at some point and the controller jsonresult has no data to use.

Comment: Hi here `pid = pidEntered` why you have `=` ? it should be `:` same for all other parameter as well . After changing this see if you have any error inside your browser console .

Comment: Hi @Swati I'm not sure what happened there, I think I saw a few different solutions online that either chose '=' or ':' for that and I chose the wrong one to go with. That has fixed my javascript not being called, so thank you very much for that. Only issue is, it falls over and fails when the ajax request is actually sent. Gives me a 500 error, so I'm having a dig around my code now.